# Grafana: global variables to access [from,to] values of the time range

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am doing some tests with a MySQL data-source and make use of the [timefilter](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/#the-timefilter-or-timefilter-variable) inside the SQL query:

```
// my query goes here...
WHERE $__timeFilter(time_start);
```

which generates something like the following:

```
WHERE time_start >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1505207821) AND time_start <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1505229421);
```

Are there any variables that can give me access to the 2 timestamps that define the time range?

For instance, at the example above:

```
from = 1505207821
to = 1505229421
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `$__timeFrom()` and `$__timeTo()` if you are using the latest 4.5.1 version of Grafana (earlier versions of Grafana only include an alpha version of the MySQL data source). There is a "Show Help" button under the query field where all the macros are listed. See below:

[image]

The first two macros return from and to in the datetime format, the last two return them as epochs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to edit the time filter. 
If the user selects now-15m to now, I wanted to show now-15m to now-5m, since last 5 min data is mostly not fully formed.
This answer helps.

Comment: How would I use it in the timeFilter query mentioned by OP?

Comment: @trail99 an example of using the $__timeFrom() macro in the where clause:


WHERE time_start > $__timeFrom()

Comment: Docs for MySQL data source with some macro examples: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#macros

Answer (score 0):

Generated Query, Doesn't fit inside the grafana time range. So you can simply change the time range.

Query From and To Fit inside the time range of the query.

[image]

I have added the time range of 100y (100 years) it fit's into my query. so you can adjust your time range accordingly,

[image]